# How to plot a circle in gnuplot with radius on the y, z plane?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like plot a circle in gnuplot with a radius in the y, z plane.

I can do `set object 1 circle at 1,1 size scr 0.1` and have it show in the x, y plane. How can I have the radius be in the y, z plane? Also, I would I make the circle visible in in `splot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` doesn't work with 3D plots (as stated in the help), but it's not difficult to create a circle using the `splot` command itself.

Using the pseudofile `'+'`, you can:

```
circle_radius=0.1
circle_x=0
circle_y=0
circle_z=0
splot "+" using (circle_x):(circle_x+circle_radius*cos(2*pi*$0/99)):(circle_z+circle_radius*sin(2*pi*$0/99)) w l
```

if you change the sampling rate (`set sample`), you should adjust the `99` to your new x-sample minus 1.